# puzzling python index error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is a piece of python code ("result" is a nested list created before)

```
for i in range(len(result)-1):
    try:
        result[i][3]=0
        result[i+i][0]=0
    except IndexError:
        print "fail", result[i][3], result[i+1][0], i, len(result)
return result
```

which, to my astonishment, quite often prints "fail" (with non-revealing values for i, len(result), e.g. 24, 31). How can

```
result[i][3]=0
result[i+i][0]=0
```

produce the IndexError exception, if

```
print result[i][3], result[i+1][0]
```

does not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are accessing the index `i + i`, *not* `i + 1`:

```
result[i+i][0]=0
```

This means that by the time you reach `i // 2 + 1` you have an index error, whatever the size of your list.